# why the setTimeout doesn't work in javascript?

Tags: click, settimeout

I'm making the simon game and It supposed when you click any button It should do like a little "flash" but I don't know it doesn't work

```js
function animatePress(currentColour) {
   
    $("#" + currentColour).addClass("pressed")
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#" + currentColour).removeClass("pressed")
    },100)
    
}
```

I'm sure that setTimeout is correct in the code, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Please show your CSS. Have you included jQuery?

Comment: yes I did , the only thing it doesn't work is this 
.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it has to do with [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) since you have elements with a color `id` I assume you use the `#id{...}` to set background colors while you are relying on the added class to change the color. You need a more specific selector to override the styles.

```js
function animatePress(currentColour) {

  $("#" + currentColour).addClass("pressed")

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#" + currentColour).removeClass("pressed")
  }, 1000)

}

for (const color of ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']) {
  animatePress(color)
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#red.pressed,
#blue.pressed,
#green.pressed,
#yellow.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='red'></td>
    <td id='blue'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='green'></td>
    <td id='yellow'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```